# Why Does The Screen Flash White Then Go Dark in Night Mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've had a night mode feature on my website for some time now. At first I was getting this weird error. When I had it turned on then refreshed the page it would turn white just for a split second, as if it was turned off, then go back to dark. It was working fine for about a year until just now, oddly enough. I didn't even edit anything in my files.

I have local storage remember if it's supposed to be light or dark when the page loads. This changes when you click on some text through javascript. In my css I have a styling for everything in light mode then when dark mode is on it adds a class to everything using javascript. In the css I have it that makes things dark.

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' type='text/css'>

    </head>

    <body>

        <nav id="nav">
            <h1>Test Page</h1>
            <p id="lightSwitchOn">Turn on Night Mode</p>
            <p id="lightSwitchOff">Turn off Night Mode</p>
        </nav>
        <div id="mainContent">
            <p>This is a test for nightmode</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="scripts/lightSwitch.js">
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
html {
    animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes color {
    from { color: inherit; }
    to { color: #3CB371; }
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    background-color: #3fcbff;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    padding: 25px;
}

body.dark {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: black;
}

nav {
    background-color: #00aced;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

nav.dark {
    background-color: #1C1C1C;
}

/*Links*/
a {
    color: #1C1C1C;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.dark {
    color: #FFF;
}

a:hover {
    animation: color .5s;
    color: #3CB371;
}

#lightSwitchOn {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#lightSwitchOn.dark {
    display: none;
}

#lightSwitchOff {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#lightSwitchOff.dark {
    display: inline;
}

#mainContent {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #00aced;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#mainContent.dark {
        background-color: #1C1C1C;
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleDocumentLoad);

function handleDocumentLoad() {

  var offSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff");
  var onSwitch = document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn");

  if (offSwitch == null) {
      //Do Nothing
  } else {
      offSwitch.addEventListener('click', lightsOn);
  }

  if (onSwitch == null) {
      //Do Nothing
  } else {
      onSwitch.addEventListener('click', lightsOff);
  }

  function lightsOff() {
    localStorage.setItem('lights', 'off');

    document.body.classList.add('dark');
    for(i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
        document.links[i].classList.add('dark');
    }

    document.getElementById("nav").classList.add('dark');

    document.getElementById("mainContent").classList.add('dark');

    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff").classList.add('dark');

    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn").classList.add('dark');
  }

  function lightsOn() {
    localStorage.setItem('lights', 'on');

    document.body.classList.remove('dark');
    for(i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
        document.links[i].classList.remove('dark');
    }

    document.getElementById("nav").classList.remove('dark');

    document.getElementById("mainContent").classList.remove('dark');

    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOff").classList.remove('dark');

    document.getElementById("lightSwitchOn").classList.remove('dark');
  }

  if(localStorage.getItem('lights') === 'off') {
      lightsOff();
  } else {
      lightsOn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey could you fix it?

Comment: I did fix it @Zak, I've changed the js and changed the css slightly too. Do you need to know?